# does a reader for spring batch have to be an injected bean?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

The transaction model in Spring batch is not so easy to understand, therefore I wonder where spring batch really needs to have proxies to fulfill all its work.

So does Spring need to create proxies around Readers, Writers, Processors and Steps and therefore I have to inject them as beans? or is it OK to no use injection for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring only uses proxies within batch when you're using step scope.  Otherwise, the beans are created and injected.  With regards to not using injection for them, you can take that approach but there is a lot going on under the covers that you'd need to handle yourself so it's not recommended.

Comment: funny thing is, that StepScope is exactly my problem, I'm not able to mark my reader with StepScope - I always get: "Scope 'step' is not active for the current thread" - "No context holder available for step scope". But creating the reader within the step confiugration seems to resolve the issues...